# django-postman extends a base.html that does not exist

Tags: python, django

I have installed and configured `django-postman` based on [documentation](https://django-postman.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

in `urls.py` in root of my project:

```
(r'^messages/', include('postman.urls')),
```

in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'grappelli',
    'filebrowser',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'south',
    'postman',
    'MeetingManagerHub',
    'PersonHub',
    'TaskManagerHub',
    'AgencyHub',
    'DrHub',
    'CompanyHub',
    'AdvHub',
    'CarHub',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'easy_maps',
    'MagazineHub',
    'captcha',
    'pagination'
)
```

so I enter the address: `http://127.0.0.1:8081/messages/inbox/`
but when I click on links none of them works!I just see this page!
[image]
**update** :

I created an man_base.html file with this content:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
{% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block postman_menu %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

and added this line to the start of `base.html` file:

```
{% extends "postman/main_base.html" %}
```

and It worked!

Comment: What errors are shown in your javascript console when the page loads and is clicked?

Comment: What is the URL for each of the links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the expected `base.html` to your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` root?

> The postman/base.html template extends a base.html site template, in
>   which some blocks are expected: title: in , at
>   least for a part of the entire title string extrahead: in
>   , to put some  and  elements content: in
>   , to put the page contents postman_menu: in ,
>   to put a navigation menu

Also not the rant on media files on the [same page](https://django-postman.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation)

Comment: base.html extends another base.html that django can't find It,so I removed the line {% extends "base.html" %} from base.html !!

Comment: Don't do that, create a base.html with the expected elements!