# TemplateNotFound after installing django-messages and django-postman

Tags: django, django-messages

I get a TemplateNotFound after I installed django-postman and django-messages. I obviously installed them separately - first django-postman, and then django-messages. This is so simple and yet I've spent hours trying to resolve this.

I'm using Django 1.8, a fresh base install using pip. I then installed the two above packages. The TEMPLATES portion of my settings.py file is as follows:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), 
            #os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/django_messages'), 
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Within my INSTALLED_APPS tuple, I've also installed the above packages as well.

Here's my addition to urls.py:

```
url(r'^messages/', include('django_messages.urls')),
```

No other changes were made to the system and yet when I go to /messages I get the following error message:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /messages/inbox/
django_messages/inbox.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/messages/inbox/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
django_messages/inbox.html
Exception Location: /projects/.virtualenvs/blatter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in render_to_string, line 138
Python Executable:  /projects/.virtualenvs/blatter/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

Comment: Have you included `django-postman` and `django-messages` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, let me update my question.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because it extends from the site's base.html. It is also mentioned in postman documentation :-  https://django-postman.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#templates

```
The postman/base.html template extends a base.html site template, in which some blocks are expected:

    title: in <html><head><title>, at least for a part of the entire title string
    extrahead: in <html><head>, to put some <script> and <link> elements
    content: in <html><body>, to put the page contents
    postman_menu: in <html><body>, to put a navigation menu
```

A possible solution can be found here :- [django-postman extends a base.html that does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832891/django-postman-extends-a-base-html-that-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved for django-messages after reviewing a called template and changing the extends/inheritance parameter.

The file that was being called, inbox.html, inherited "django_messages/base.html" ... which worked fine. "base.html" then inherited from "base.html," so there appeared to be some circular logic here causing the error. This is by default and wasn't added by me. When I removed the extends/inheritance declaration from "base.html" so that it didn't inherit from itself, django-messages worked.

Perhaps Django 1.8 changed some logic w/templates? Either way, issue resolved.

Comment: Confirmed, was able to reproduce issue. Your solution works for me.

Comment: Note that it's not trying to inherit itself - `base.html` refers to a different template than `django_messages/base.html`.